# Harnack inequalities for Markov chains

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

We consider a (continuous time) Markov chain $X=(\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0},\{P_x\}_{x \in V})$ on a finite set $V$. We assume moreover that $V$ is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^d$. The generator $\mathcal{L}$ of $X$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}f(x)=\sum_{y \in V}P(x,y)f(y)-f(x),\quad x \in V,\, f \in \mathbb{R}^V.
\end{align*}
Here, $P(x,y)$ denotes the transition probability of $X$. Let $A \subset V$ and $h \colon A  \to \mathbb{R}$ a function on $A$. We say that $h$ is harmonic on $A$ if $\mathcal{L}h(x)=0$ for $x \in A$.

I am concerned with a Harnack inequality for these harmonic functions. The inequality means that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{y \in B(x,r/2)}h(y) \le C \inf_{y \in B(x,r/2)}h(y)
\end{align*}
for a harmonic function $h$ on $B(x,r)=\{y \in V \mid |y-x|<r\}$. Here, $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean distance, and $C$ denotes a positive constant independent of $x$ and $h$.

What assumptions can be made for $V$ and $P$ to obtain this kind of inequality?

If $V$ is a finite set, I think it should be obtained under a mild assumption, but is that wrong?

Comment: If $C$ is allowed to depend on $B(x,r)$, then Harnack's inequality indeed holds under the assumption that all states communicate within your domain $D = B(x,r)$. However, such a result is usually not interesting. On the other hand, if $C$ is to be uniform in some sense, Harnack's inequality seems to be more demanding than in the continuous setting, following the usual rule that discrete structures require subtler arguments than their continuous counterparts.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your comment. As you say, I started to think that the discrete setting is "usually" more difficult to derive the Harnack's inequality than the continuous case.